# Смена цвета при фоне и добавление текста уже в готовые скрипт

Tags: css-animation, javascript

Здравствуйте! Нужно сделать так, чтобы цвет текста изменился, когда до него дошло один цвет фона. Т. е. так - https://www.dropbox.com/s/u06nozsj4sw71qc/download2.png
Скрипт есть вот он - http://jsfiddle.net/anGGP/2/. Еще надо добавить текст перед процента (Загружено более n-ое кол-во %).

Comment: Никто не поможет? ;(

Comment: а с чем вам помочь ? что значит:

> когда до него дошло один цвет фона.

Comment: я же пример показал.

Comment: есть исходный цвет фона, пока он не дошел исходный цвет надписи. Когда он заливает текст, цвет текста меняется.

Comment: т.е. сделайте это за вас ? 

**вы даже текст добавить сами не в состоянии** это не помощь а работа.

сделайте два div, один с одним фоном, другой с другим, анимируйте один на увеличение, другой на уменьшение, `overflow: none;`

Comment: текст то сделать сам смогу. Не уж-то никто не поможет с цветами?(

Comment: я новичок в этом деле, мне бы готовое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так?
http://jsfiddle.net/QeKN2/1/
Вы как-то совсем не умеете вопросы задавать.